# Align confidence intervals one below the other

Tags: python, dataframe, confidence-interval

Say I have a pandas dataframe in which 3 columns are of interest: an `id` (text), a `min` and a `max` (float) representing the lower and upper bound of a confidence interval of some parameter (in %), such as:

```
id   min   max
 A   3.5   7.8
 B  11.35 13.25
 C   0.0   2.0
```

I would like to represent these data in a plot (as seen below) with the `ids` located under each other on the vertical axis, and each line showing the variation of the confidence interval of the corresponding `id`.

[image]

And, of course, my question is: is there a (quite) simple way to do so in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no chart for plotting confidence intervals in particular. However, you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.barh()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html). The code is following.

Data frame preparation:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
...         'min': [3.5, 11.35, 0.0],
...         'max': [7.8, 13.25, 2.0]
...     }
... )
>>> df = df.sort_values(by='id', ascending=False)
>>> print(df)
  id    min    max
2  C   0.00   2.00
1  B  11.35  13.25
0  A   3.50   7.80
```

Making a chart:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.style.use('seaborn')
>>> 
>>> plt.figure(figsize=(9.5, 2.5))
>>> plt.barh(df['id'], height=0.5, width=df['max']-df['min'], left=df['min'])
>>> plt.title('Chart title')
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jaroslav for this intuitive solution, which fits well with what I know how to handle with Python. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In python, we can be solve it using matplotlib library using below code.

Have also attached the output image for the same.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd


id = ["A","B","C"]
min =[3.5,1.35,0.0]
max =[7.8, 13.25, 2.0]

data = [id,min,max]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T
df.columns=["id","min","max"]


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    m2m = np.linspace( row['min'],row['max'])
    y_val = np.array([row["id"] for _ in range(len(m2m))])
    plt.plot(m2m, y_val )
```

[**Output Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPcnJ.png)